# mail() function - sending a HTML template

Tags: php, email, include

I'm having a little trouble configuring my mail function. I've been trying to set it up so that I can keep my HTML template seperate to my class file. I wanted to do something like the below.

```
mail('email@email.com', 'subject here', include('email/template.html'), 'from@from.com');
```

Although it doesn't seem to like it, is there anyway to do it other than have a really long message string?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) instead of `include`. `include` processes the file and outputs to the stream (data going to client), not just returning the contents--otherwise you'd be `echo include('...')` all the time.

Though realistically, if you're looking for this kind of "advanced" ability (and your host supports it) [PEAR Mail](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail/redirected) is a better option.

Comment: Thank you your option seems to work, although it's not parsing it as Html rather just plain text. Do I need to update the headers?

Comment: @user863739: You can create a new [Mail_mime](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail-mime.example.php) and play with the content type, yes.

Answer (score 1):

`include()` doesn't return the contents of a file. it executes the file. That means any PHP code within the file is executed, and any "bare" html is output to the client. The only thing include() returns is a true/false value to indicate success/failure.

It's a bad design, but you'd want something like this:

```
ob_start();
include('email/template.html');
$email_text = ob_get_clean();

mail('email@gmail.com', 'subject', $email_text, ....);
```

The [output buffering](http://php.net/ob_start) functions will capture the "output" of the include and return it into that $email_text var, which you then pass to the mail() function.

note that this method is only required if you want the .html page to be executed as PHP. If it's truly just plain html, you can use file_get_contents() instead, which saves you a PHP parse/compile/execute sequence.

Comment: Just as a note, OB (Output Buffering) is only required if you need PHP to process the files you're trying to read. If you're only going after contents, fopen/fread/fclose or file_get_contents is a better approach. -- **EDIT** It looks like you updated your post to include what my comments essentially mention. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Your "include()" statement is being misused... try this:

```
$template = file_get_contents('email/template.html');
mail('email@email.com', 'subject here', $template, 'from@from.com');
```

Don't use the `include` directive unless you are actually including a file that you want to interpret as part of the page—it's bad programming practice.  The answer above which uses ob_start() include() ob_get_clean();  works in a nasty way; it will actually execute the inclusion as a PHP script. Now if the template is FILLED by the user and saved by you somewhere, the user will be able to use this construct to execute arbitrary PHP code on your server. BAD BAD BAD.

Comment: Thank you Ahmed,

although it seems it's being parsed as plain text rather than HTML using file_get_contents()